# GCP IoT core rejects this RSA_PEM public key with an error

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, rsa, iot, google-cloud-iot

I try to develop an automation to register new IoT device with public RSA pem certificate but I have a problem which is I don't know the reason.

The problem is RSA_PEM public pem is generated my automation is rejected by GCP IoT Server with an error. That error is "The key data for the device credential in position 1 is invalid. Make sure the format is correct: Invalid RS256 public key"

When I debug the my code, the pem public certificate looks fine. But I am not sure that.

I am sharing go code that generate private and public certificates in paired.

```golang
package cert

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"

    "io"
)

type CertificateRSA struct {
    Private io.Reader
    Public  io.Reader
}

func Create() (*CertificateRSA, error) {

    bitSize := 2048
    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, bitSize)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var privateKey = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key),
    }

    var priBuff bytes.Buffer
    err = pem.Encode(&priBuff, privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // asn1Bytes := x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(&key.PublicKey)
    asn1Bytes := x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(&key.PublicKey)

    var publicKey = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
        Bytes: asn1Bytes,
    }

    var pubBuff bytes.Buffer

    err = pem.Encode(&pubBuff, publicKey)
    return &CertificateRSA{
        Private: &priBuff,
        Public:  &pubBuff,
    }, err
}
```

Can you see any problem in my code ?

And this code can generates certificates like as these:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA0FGWENPInhIfCLDTqCFKFsyrvmzKsEjJtHEL0Tqh0LtHDWG5
Sh7MT7/x/xNAFc00zmgGG+PPaJDP/7gkGJitRAXcJOlKwlowgmVTf+QGwH81pq3o
ZNRd0mEXbF0EuPBRNt/9TzkZPAlPDGruMCiMq9LWsoIflx+u/3UmXgsyMQTs5vSM
z4T5VCELHGCtfZfBrDAP19KzwjFEUTEzX+Llotp0mO6+cRCslVvSK3xd8KIk2cOm
AXEmCavZnwuVsqCVmNZFoQZvFszisMf5cXZRDstKCGsqDgqIGM5dMMrBS92CqZ4u
j6h9zbMG7J9oXsVmVFiQ++hS0TLJdWwMD+uhWQIDAQABAoIBAAbKIfH6dRdxz8Eg
wkVAkIGduhtCwHhuZuSSqqfvGUcMU4yEGt3nkxEmWGTP487SGV6A1XIjQqdN0Pms
rsB+eWc2Ka6qS915wwr88nPAotezTbRZBrICmew5beICRh0g+ASp2D+0xLXIN+NX
uNuo9qzC+mxnAVCTn8iDsPRvuPsP9vJSy5zIzPWURdPBQ3Ny1pbj+odqwDdUw8q7
FfUmGHC7a5oKex3vxDhDL8OPc3KjynFJdm1YqUagLzppDHMZtI2rNAYfWrkrJVB7
zlX3m0hUDDrvHbQBiqGUj2qI2MqgrFlcK0HSryJdCz4tVdYY3qBi/tZrwOAvnSkv
zNFT6AECgYEA9veJpGwUYdRhWyo05xsatDJ+KvBpizi66Iu2Lu+fRQUuwYaC0DSV
BMr1ktbJzbgbu4XDNrJ8GKrqka06vGjaYVhw1C56LU83hHsckTx+K3fpb9wkFamE
gCZG3uAqflLsEPZ6xPHLe1U+SDZfghLrH90JYi7tTULReAVy5zVs8iECgYEA1/Aq
6ls9kPtJWLEU299WdNGYy5Fx1N8oUj5sjYTfPf/27OeBXWg+CKBIhXk534z9pwqq
LUs7NbmqhuocuxFtE7oxdwqXqUR7qYUdpVuRZ8EmVvBuUGxI1MG6MMKxHxSSpTs5
3tTDAd2WlwPX3jbqAj2WOiL2T97cXNjYyKxiuDkCgYBbI0RnKf9njtGSrAOz2XvE
TfHjdK7uUrQfBxfnQER9WwlDH5l8rjrj9uYjFyKHyU5qqFU/BSTokYJY2h2X0/Xr
AJE6rCAoQliRikEjk7hX4DuELTAf0lv0UqvKqdzkm0NEi0EJFtXpoK6IRZB/Vu3v
50kEM58c6PCWIyShEEUxIQKBgQCg63qf0UTNMWaUcMqxm/sq7TNnqMjisTa0K47r
27Qd2Q1juJZATLnF5eSFizSkssYoYJs3S9QhEm7RQdANXEwkImJQaxVgcAeT6f6Q
xu9SGa9/pIcg6cFQw9oEEmK6XbN27O8Qbw+v6Tka6yNIlzXGW60DQCC8nsErc/IB
ge3DiQKBgA3183wzRLj7oZD/KJHW+BY0Y6ljZ8EQQ5anc3RFsQrJ48MdPtRNvC49
Oe0T2lRznVdiPcGY8DKlBMYXQ4jiXZxpWmM8jNkJYPBhx9rq8zBDESo8DKSFd1Jo
lNADlBGDEPYgxG29hnSOrBf5TI1Fkj15RVZOJ79uaefp98ACIgkl
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA0FGWENPInhIfCLDTqCFKFsyrvmzKsEjJtHEL0Tqh0LtHDWG5Sh7M
T7/x/xNAFc00zmgGG+PPaJDP/7gkGJitRAXcJOlKwlowgmVTf+QGwH81pq3oZNRd
0mEXbF0EuPBRNt/9TzkZPAlPDGruMCiMq9LWsoIflx+u/3UmXgsyMQTs5vSMz4T5
VCELHGCtfZfBrDAP19KzwjFEUTEzX+Llotp0mO6+cRCslVvSK3xd8KIk2cOmAXEm
CavZnwuVsqCVmNZFoQZvFszisMf5cXZRDstKCGsqDgqIGM5dMMrBS92CqZ4uj6h9
zbMG7J9oXsVmVFiQ++hS0TLJdWwMD+uhWQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: The public key is not a valid format. The header suggests a base64-encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure but the contents are actually an RSAPublicKey structure. An RSAPublicKey structure should start out "BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY".

Comment: @JamesKPolk thank you for comment. But using the header recommended by you  instead of "PUBLIC KEY" doesn't work. I am getting same error by GCP IoT Core API.

I think that my go code can't generate RSA Keys like as openssl command. For example  the outputs of this command `openssl genrsa -out rsa_private.pem 2048 && openssl rsa -in rsa_private.pem -pubout -out rsa_public.pem`  are verified by GCP IoT Core API.

Comment: I could not figure out any way to generate valid pem file via above code. So I  have written an wrapper on `ssh` command.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The signature of device credential in position 0 could not be verified against any registry certificate.
```

error and your system used to work, check the expiration date of the root CA certificate. It will return this error if it's past the date.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding header and the encoding method don't match. If you want to use

```
asn1Bytes := x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(&key.PublicKey)
```

then the `pem.Block` Type should be `Type:  "RSA PUBLIC KEY",`.

If you want the other common public key format, a SubjectPublicKeyInfo ASN.1 structure, then keep the `pem.Block` as you have it and instead use

```
asn1Bytes, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(&key.PublicKey)
```

I don't know what GCP is expecting but it's almost certainly one or the other.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Thanks. Do you happen to have a link to right docs, or is it something you discovered by trial and error?

Comment: It is more of a convention with the cloud vendors as PKCS #1 is easier to decode. However, I just looked up the IoT certificate create command: `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout rsa_private.pem -nodes -out rsa_cert.pem -subj "/CN=unused"` and that command generates PKCS #8. https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/keys

Comment: @JamesKPolk  using `RSA PUBLIC KEY` as TYPE doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
I could solve this with the following code.

```
package cloudIotCore

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "os"
)

func create() {

    //
    // Create key
    //
    reader := rand.Reader
    bitSize := 2048

    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(reader, bitSize)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    publicKeyAsc1Bytes, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(&(key.PublicKey))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    publicPemKey := &pem.Block{
        Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
        Bytes: publicKeyAsc1Bytes,
    }

    privatePemKey := &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key),
    }

    //
    // Create Device with publicPemKey
    //

    :

    //
    // Save pem files
    //

    publicPemFile, err := os.Create(PATH_TO_PUBLICKEY)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer publicPemFile.Close()

    err = pem.Encode(publicPemFile, publicPemKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    privatePemFile, err := os.Create(PATH_TO_PRIVATEKEY)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer privatePemFile.Close()

    err = pem.Encode(privatePemFile, privatePemKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a miss-match between the key format expected and the type of the key, RSA_PEM vs  RSA_X509_PEM. Switching that fixed the issue.