# Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The signature of device credential in position 0 could not be verified against any registry certificate

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-iot

I am trying to register my IoT device using a generated Service account json credentials.
The underlying library is a MQTT (bridge) and google-cloud/iot (nodejs) - this repo (https://github.com/balena-io-examples/google-iot), or [this documentation for details](https://www.balena.io/docs/learn/develop/integrations/google-iot/).

The service account json is pasted within the `ENV` variable `GOOGLE_IOT_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN`  as a single line json formatted.
When it tries to register the device and add it to the registry automatically I am getting the following error:

```
[Google IoT] Connecting to Google IoT Core ...
[Google IoT] Device ID: id-00000000000000000000000000000000
[Google IoT] Project: google-iot-project-id
[Google IoT] Region: google-iot-region
[Google IoT] Registry: google-iot-registry
[Google IoT] Device with name id-00000000000000000000000000000000 not registered. Attempting to register...
Generating a RSA private key
........................+++++
................................................................................................................................................................................................................+++++
writing new private key to 'rsa-priv.pem'
-----
read EC key
writing EC key
[MQTT] Refreshing jwt token ...
{ host: 'mqtt.googleapis.com',
  port: 8883,
  clientId:
   'projects/google-iot-project-id/locations/google-iot-region/registries/google-iot-registry/devices/id-00000000000000000000000000000000',
  username: 'unused',
  password:
   'generated-password',
  protocol: 'mqtts',
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method',
  project: 'google-iot-project-id' }
[MQTT] Opening connection ...
(node:156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The signature of device credential in position 0 could not be verified against any registry certificate.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at process.nextTick (/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:9)
(node:156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:156) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[MQTT] MQTT error { Error: Connection refused: Not authorized
```

Has anyone faced any issues using NodeJS libraries to register & use Google IoT (Core) cloud service?

Am I doing something wrong? Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/56611893/421195 and here: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/verifying-credentials.  If you get it working, please post your solution as a "Reply", then "Accept" it.

Comment: @paulsm4: I can confirm to you that I am aware of the links which you provided to me! Did double check on both pages and none of the solutions worked for me. I have posted because I feel that its an edge case.